# git-buildpackage complains of unavailability *.orig.tar.gz of the source downloaded?

Tags: linux, git, debian

I am building compiz from git source. uses git-buildpackage. this particular repository has no pristine-tar branch.
http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=pkg-xorg/app/compiz.git

How can I create *.orig.tar.gz tarball for the source? Show Me a Documentation/Howto when repository does not have pristine-tar branch.
if it helps, below is the debian/gbp.conf . and this is a Debian Testing/Unstable amd64 System.

```
cat debian/gbp.conf 
[DEFAULT]
debian-branch = debian-unstable
debian-tag = compiz-%(version)s
upstream-branch = upstream-unstable
upstream-tag = compiz-%(version)s
[git-dch]
meta = 1
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you have to branch version trees using "git branch" command to have git-buildpackage build debian package as well as debianized(.orig.tar.gz) archive for you.
sorry for the trouble. N00b know :|